# Exclude documents content results in SharePoint Online Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, metadata

We implemented the search  on the document library  having the items more than 100000 items  with 8-12 metadata properties in SharePoint online as per the customer requirements, which was working fine.

Currently the search results contains items based on the content search and metadata properties. Now we need omit the items based on the content search(exclude documents content) . we need to display search results based on only meta data properties

Any suggestions will be greatly helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways but this is the simplest:

1. Add a Search Results web part to a page
2. Edit properties
3. Click Change Query
4. In the Property Filter dropdown select Show All Managed Properties
5. Add your RefinableString properties one at a time separated by a space.
6. Your Search Results web part will pull back all of the documents without having to run a KeyWord search, which I believe is what you are trying to accomplish.

Edit___________________
Even easier Click Change Query then click on the TAB labeled REFINERS

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Using Display Template  we  can change the UI of the search results. But i need to exclude the results based on the document  content.

Comment: You mentioned you have documents and they all have metadata.  What are you trying to exclude?  Which documents?

Comment: I need to exclude the search results returned based on the content and display only  results based on the meta data properties

Comment: Have you mapped your custom columns to Managed Properties?

Comment: Yes Mapped to RefinableStrings

Comment: Please see my edited answer.  It wouldn't let me add screenshots. :-(

Comment: But now i am able to add the values for the refiners not the refiners

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, You can map crawled properties(not include the context) to a managed property, then use this managed property in the query. Like this: **managed property:value**

Comment: Thanks for the reply,My first thought was the same approach and implemented successfully. But user are reporting that this approach is not user friendly. So searching for  other approaches to meet the exact requirement.

Comment: It's by default the search results will show the content  unless you use the managed property. So I think there is no other ways to meet your requirement.